# how to display a local file.html

Tags: android, html, xml

It is easy to display a html page with a webView. As below:

```
why = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
String htmlStr = "http://myhtml";
why.loadUrl(htmlStr);
```

But my difficulty is to display a html page with file.html locally.
Where is what I should put my file.html in my project and how the call with WebView?

Thank you for your reply, and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put that `.html` file in your project's `assets` folder and use with below code -

```
WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview1);
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
      {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
      }
    });
```